# How do I dominate Milligan?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

In the quest "Necromantic" in *Vampire: The Masquerade - Bloodlines*, I read from IGN and GameFAQS(probably the same source) that I can make Milligan forget everything and earn a humanity point by not sending him to Pisha. Problem is, I can't figure out how to do it. I'm playing as a Tremere, I already tried putting a point on Dominate and using Brain Wipe on the guy but it doesn't work. No conversation options show for him forgetting everything too, plus there's no stat for Dominate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Dominate options in conversations are only available to Ventrue. With the Wesp + patch, Tremere get access to a few of the most basic ones, but for the most part, it's a Ventrue only perk. (And not a particularly good one, TBQH.)

Comment: Oh well, must suck it up then. Figuratively. Thanks!